# query to fetch the mostly winning user

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables film and users , i am using this query to fetch the users who are the winners

```
$winners_query=("Select * from users where user_id IN (Select user_id from film where iswinningclip=1) order by user_id desc limit 12");
```

I have difficulty to write a query to sort the data in such way that the user who is winner most times should comes first and so on.

this does not work for me

```
$winners_query=("Select * from users where user_id IN (Select count(user_id) AS CN from film where iswinningclip=1 oder by CN desc) order by user_id desc limit 12");
```

users table contains user_id and and other related fields and film table contains film_id, user_id, iswinningclip
Can someone suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Can you show us the structure of the two tables on this one?

Comment: Edit your question and who sample data and desired results.

Comment: See [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) . Load it up. Show Expect Results. Help us to help you :p ... If that link is too confusing, go to Section 2 of it

Comment: @Liza Ash I have given an answer with an example.Check to see if that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one it will help you.

```
SELECT  users.*, count(film.user_id) as no_of_awards
FROM  users join film  
On (users.user_id = film.user_id)
WHERE film.iswinningclip = 1
Group by users.user_id
Order by no_of_awards DESC
```

Comment: This worked man, now i have problem that i am using ajax for paging as the user scrolls records
expands, , i have been passing user_id in ajax so that when user scrolls 
this should be executed '$winners_query=("Select users.*,count(film.user_id) as no_of_awards from users JOIN film On (users.user_id = film.user_id) WHERE film.iswinningclip = 1   and users.user_id < $get_id Group by users.user_id Order by no_of_awards DESC limit 12");' Now what should i pass in the url so that users with less awards comes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly select userid and iswinningclip, then apply group by userid, so you will get total count of iswinningclip, then apply max function on that column. That is id who won.

Comment: `select userid, count(iswinning) AS x from film group by userid order by x desc`  : here coloumns are userid, filmid and iswinning (this coloumn is just having 1 and 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join in this case otherwise the query you used looks more complex

```
SELECT  users.*, film.*
FROM  users 
inner join
film  
On (users.id = film.user_id)
WHERE film.iswinningclip = 1
Group by users.id
Order by count(users.id) DESC
```

Comment: what should be the condition?

Comment: what do you want exactly in your query put in where condition

Comment: i want the user to come up first whose clips are iswinningclip=1 maximum times

Comment: it is giving total number of winning clips

Answer (score 0):

Use a join of the two tables on user_id, give the condition as winningclip=1, apply group by userid and finally order the results based on the count of user_ids in descending order

The query should be like

```
SELECT 
    u.id, u.username, u.gender //select as many columns you want from users
FROM
    users u
        JOIN
    film f ON (u.id = f.user_id)
WHERE
    f.iswinningclip = 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY COUNT(u.id) DESC
```

Full Example

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE film (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT NULL,
  film_id INT NULL,
  iswinningclip INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));


INSERT INTO users (username, gender) VALUES ('Kiran', 'M');
INSERT INTO users (username, gender) VALUES ('Liza', 'F');
INSERT INTO users (username, gender) VALUES ('Ajith', 'M');

INSERT INTO  film (film_id, user_id, iswinningclip) VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO  film (film_id, user_id, iswinningclip) VALUES ('1', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO  film (film_id, user_id, iswinningclip) VALUES ('2', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO  film (film_id, user_id, iswinningclip) VALUES ('2', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO  film (film_id, user_id, iswinningclip) VALUES ('3', '3', '1');

SELECT 
    u.id, u.username, u.gender
FROM
    users u
        JOIN
    film f ON (u.id = f.user_id)
WHERE
    f.iswinningclip = 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY COUNT(u.id) DESC
```

Result

[image]